# Why does the data event only stop the NodeJS run time from exiting?

Tags: node.js, sockets

Take the following code in nodejs-:

```
console.log("Hello world");
process.stdin.on('connect', function() {

    });
```

This prints Hello World and then Node exits. But when I replace the connect event with 'data' event, the Node runtime does not exit.

Why is that ? What is so special about the EventEmitter's data event ? Does it open a socket connection ? So in the on() method is there code like the following -:

```
function on(event, callback) {
if(event === 'data') {
     //open socket
     //do work
    }
else {
   //do non-socket work
   }
}
```

Is there a clear answer to why adding a listener to the data event "magically" open a socket.

Comment: There's nothing special about the 'data' event. It's an event like any other event.

Comment: @ralphtheninja That's great. Then why doesn't the nodejs runtime exit when we attach a listener for the data event, but exits when we attach a listener for any other event

Comment: Hard to say. Would be nice if you could show some more code.

Comment: @ralphtheninja I am learning Node. Thats all the code that I have. Just paste it in and execute it. Then switch the connect to data and see the difference in the behaviour

Comment: Oh right. It's most likely an implementation detail of `process.stdin`.

Comment: What I mean by this is that the 'data' event on any EventEmitter would not lock the process, but when you add an event listener to `process.stdin` then the process waits for input on stdin.

Comment: @ng.newbie FWIW, most likely, `connect` is an event that will have already fired when you add a listener for it; I assume that `process.stdin` will have been set up before any user code will run. Also, `data` events _are_ special in some ways: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_two_modes

Answer (score 1):

Node.js event loop has couple phases of processing, in your case it's `poll` phase. Which process for example incoming data (`process.stdin.on('data', cb)`) so until there is a callback that can handle this event, a this event can occur, node event loop is not empty and node will not exit.

`process.stdin` is Readable Stream which has fallowing events:

- close
- data
- end
- error
- readable

so there is nothing like `connect`.

```
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
    console.log('Readable');
});
```

Code above will print `Readable` and exit because after firing event stream is not in `flowing` state so it will exit event loop because it's empty, but `data` event sets stream state to `flowing`, 
so if stream state is set to `flowing` and if `readableState.reading` is `true` it will prevent node to exit.
if you do

```
process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

if you write anything in console when this is running it will work like echo.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_readable.js#L774-L795

You can read full explanation how event loop works here https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Comment: What I fail to understand from your answer, is that when I attach a listener, why does it wait for data to be received ? And when I don't attach a listener nothing happens, does the poll phase vanish then ? Functions like fs.readFile actually do some work then call the callback, but attaching a listener for the data event does nothing. Why wait then ?

Comment: Also which events belong to the poll phase and which events belong to the timer phase. I think I am looking at this from a wrong angle. Could you please add the intuition of how to write Node programs.

Comment: So streams that are set to 'flowing' stop node from exiting right ?

Comment: You might want adding that to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume `index.js` contains

```
process.stdin.on('data', console.log)
```

and you do `node index.js`, then the process waits for input on `stdin`.

If you send some data on stdin via e.g. `echo woohoo | node index.js` then the buffer will be written and the process exits.